# How to make a edit button in a h:dataTable to make a row editable

Tags: jsf

I got a HtmlDatatable with

- One CommandButton to Edit.
- One CommandButton to Save.
- One InputText to display info.

```
    <h:form>            
      <h:dataTable var="entity" value="#{bean.entities}">
        <h:column>
         <f:facet name="header">ColumnA</f:facet>
         <h:commandButton value="edit" actionListenner="#{bean.edit()}" />
         <hcommandButton value="save" actionListenner="#{bean.save(entity)} rendered="false"/>
         <h:inputText value="#{entity.value}"/>
         </h:column>
      </h:dataTable>            
    </h:form>
```

I would like when i click the CommandButton edit that the CommandButton save appear. How can i access the CommandButton save inside my method edit() from the bean ?

- Is the ONLY WAY to do it is to pass the clientId from the button.
- Or Is there ANOTHER WAY by passing the object itself instead as parameter of the EL and work with it in the method directly ? #{bean.edit(buttonSave)}

```
    public void edit()
    {
      //TODO get the button save from the same row as the button triggered.

      //TODO switch rendered to true.
    }
```

Comment: Learn about ajax...

Answer (score 1):

Dont try to access your CommandButton save inside the edit() method. Add a boolean attriubte called something like editMode to your entity and try passing your entity to your edit method like this

```
<h:commandButton value="edit" actionListenner="#{bean.edit(entity)}" />
```

Now in your edit() method, add your entity as param and enable the edit mode on your entity

```
public void edit(Entity entity)
{
    entity.setEditMode(true);
}
```

It is now possible with EL to make the rendered attribute of your commandButton to check the editMode of your entity like this

```
<h:commandButton value="edit" actionListenner="#{bean.edit(entity)}" rendered="#{!entity.editMode}"/>    
<h:commandButton value="save" actionListenner="#{bean.save(entity)}" rendered="#{entity.editMode}"/>
```

So if the editMode attribute is true, you now should see the save button. The same way you can hide your edit button

Comment: thank you for your answer, it looks good but i am wondering where is the editMode field located is it inside the Object annotated with "@Entity" object ? Is it something automatically present in the Object or added by the dev ?

Comment: it is added by the dev. If you are using JPA you can add the annotation @Transient to the property so it is not persisted to the db

Comment: Thank you for this solution this is a good way to make it. I am also thinking that entity should not contain variable that change the UI. so it should be contained in the Bean view itself. So i put a variable in the bean view instead. Now i really don't know how it should be done for only one row is in edit mode ? So my orginale question still remain open.